# How can I open a TCP socket in node and also use http.request?

Tags: node.js, sockets, http, tcp, request

Using node.js I'm trying to read from a series of HTTP requests, parse the data and then write to a TCP socket for ingestion into a data service.

It seems that when there is a socket open, `http.request` gets errors.

I have stripped this code down to just the problem itself:

```
var net = require('net');
var http = require('http');

var socket = net.createConnection(9997);

var req = http.request("http://www.google.com", function(response) {
    var body = '';

    response.on('data', function(c) {
        body += c;
    });

    response.on('end', function() {
        console.log(body);
    });
});
req.end();
```

This will fail with:

```
events.js:85 
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1010:19)
```

However, if you comment out the line beginning with `var socket` the http.request call runs just fine.

Can anyone shed any light on why I can't use http.request once a socket is open on an unrelated port?

Thanks!

Comment: Apparently there is not a TCP socket server running on port 9997 to listen to the socket attempting to connect.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, it was really that simple. I needed to start the server first. Strange, though, that the error lay in the http.request call and not with the socket instance...